# Modify a control (winforms) through another thread

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
Public Class main

    Public Shared classOne As classOne 
    Public Shared classTwo As classTwo

    Public Shared Sub main()

        classOne = new classOne()
        classTwo = new classTwo()

        classTwo.myThread.Start()

        Application.Run(classOne)
    End Sub

End Class
```

classOne is a simple winforms with a textlabel. I just would like modify the background color of this textlabel from classTwo but there is a problem because classTwo is in an other thread.

I know I must use a delegate and invoke method but i don't know how to do it. Where should I declare the delegate function and where I have to use invoke method please? I have already ridden the MSDN documentation but I failed to apply it...

Comment: And did you read some of entries in the `related` column here on the right side?

Comment: Yes...that didn't help me....

Comment: This one seems to help.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18649951/74015

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update UI form from worker thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980130/update-ui-form-from-worker-thread)

Answer (score -2):

Please read the following articles:

[MSDN - How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[MSDN - How to: Use a Background Thread to Search for Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8xdz5c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[MSDN - Control.Invoke Method (Delegate, Object())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[MSDN - Control.InvokeRequired Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

i guess this is too much for people. :\